# How can I make the EditText expandable and hide icons when it is clicked in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I am making a messaging app and wanted a textfield to look like this:

[image]

And when the editText is clicked, it will look like this:

[image]

And when you clicked **"+"** it will again show the camera and gallery icon. Similar to Facebook Messenger mobile app's chat text.

How can I make something like this in my layout?

Comment: You can do something like, on textchange listener. And then make them gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way to do it is adding `setOnFocusChangeListener` on your EditText, and in that listener you have to change the **Visibility** of icons to `View.GONE`. Analogically with clearing the text/changing focus you have to change the visibility to `View.VISIBLE`. It will scale nice and easy if you're using **ConstraintLayout**. Hope it helps, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use ExpandableLayout and customize it so it shows upwards instead of the downward direction it always expands to.